# minimize footprint jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I have already a newly created custom jquery plugin, my question is how to minimize its footprint? like from lines of codes into "1 line" only like other jquery plugin author does.

example:

From this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cPlugin = function () {
        //lines of codes here
        // another line of codes here
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Into this:

```
(function($){$.fn.cPlugin = function(){//lines of codes here and // another line of codes here}}(jQuery));
```

Comment: you want to minify the plugin?

Comment: **http://jscompress.com/** will do it for you.

Comment: uglifyjs, which is a node.js project does a fab job.

Comment: Yes I want to minify my newly created plugin. :)

Comment: Also try 

http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

Comment: Thank you @Archer.. This one suits my question. :))

TomChew, Juhana and Paul: Thanks for the suggestions guys. :)

Comment: I think this website can do it for you. https://jscompressor.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these :-

http://javascript-minifier.com/

http://www.jsmini.com/

http://jscompress.com/

Answer (score 0):

The current state-of-the-art Javascript minifiers are

- UglifyJS2

  - Online: http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs
  - Downloadable: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2
- Google Closure Compiler

  - Online: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home
  - Downloadable: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

Run your code (once it's all done and ready for production!) through one of those and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this frequently, you may want a command line application. You can use the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) for this task.

Command line invocation:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js plugin.js --js_output_file plugin.min.js
```

Output is a file containing:

```
(function(a){a.fn.cPlugin=function(){}})(jQuery);
```